# Using list comprehension and datetime to generate a list of times in python

Tags: python, datetime, list-comprehension, iso8601, timedelta

I am trying to create a list that is generated by using list comprehension that uses 1 minute increments.  Then it would convert the dates/times into the ISO 8601 format.  This is what I was thinking the solution would look like:

```py
import datetime as dt

t1 = dt.datetime(2001, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0)

t2 = dt.datetime(2001, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0)

time = [t1 + dt.timedelta(minutes = x) for x in range((t2-t1).total_seconds()/60)]

isotime = time.isoformat()
```

Is this semi correct?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you post what you expect `isotime` to be?

Comment: Instead of asking us, why not print out the list and see?

Comment: Your solution does not work for me.

Comment: Since you have 5 days - are you looking for a list of 7200 entries?

Answer (score 1):

think this might be easier using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
t1 = pd.to_datetime('2001-10-10 00:00:00')
t2 = pd.to_datetime('2001-10-15 00:00:00')
series = pd.date_range(t1,t2,freq='1min')
iso8601 = [t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H:%M%SZ') for t in series]

output:

['20011010T00:0000Z', '20011010T00:0100Z', '20011010T00:0200Z', '20011010T00:0300Z', ... ,  
'20011014T23:5700Z', '20011014T23:5800Z', '20011014T23:5900Z', '20011015T00:0000Z']
```

Comment: I can use this as well since the boss doesn't care if I use pandas or not, thanks for the other method!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `isoformat` on every item in the `time` list:

```
isotime = [t.isoformat() for t in time]
```

Also note that `range` accepts only integers. You should change `range((t2-t1).total_seconds()/60)` to `range(int((t2-t1).total_seconds()/60))`

Though, the best thing is to use `pandas` as @Derek Eden suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Try these tweaks:

- Use `.isoformat()` inside the comprehension.
- Use `int()` to ensure that `range()` gets in integer instead of a float.

This should work:

```
import datetime as dt

t1 = dt.datetime(2001, 10, 10)
t2 = dt.datetime(2001, 10, 15)

isotimes = [
    (t1 + dt.timedelta(minutes=minutes)).isoformat()
    for minutes in range(int((t2 - t1).total_seconds() // 60))
]
```

You could also use a big library like `pandas`, though that would cause a time penalty at import.